# Searching String to Xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<AccessUrl>  
  <Url>/User/Index</Url>
  <Url>/EmailAccounts/Index</Url>
  <Url>/Registration/Index</Url>
</AccessUrl>
```

I have a xml file. I wand to search a string in it.  I have written a C# code for it.

> ```
> string Url="/User/Index";// or One of the above value from file.
> var CheckPermission = (from a in doc.Elements("AccessUrl")
>                                    where a.Element("Url").Value.Contains(Url)
>                                    select a).Any();
> ```

but it only works OK with first Url value from file. But if i change the `string Url="/EmailAccounts/Index";`. It doesn't show any match even the url value exists in xml file.Well i tried a lot but didn't get succeed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `a.Element("Url")` gives you the first child element with specified name. You should go through all children instead with something like:

```
a.Elements("Url").Any(u => u.Value.Contains(Url))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling:

```
where a.Element("Url")
```

This will return the first matching element.

From the docs:

> Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified System.Xml.Linq.XName

You need to use something like this to check all elements:

```
var CheckPermission = (from a in doc.Descendants("Url")
                               where a.Value.Contains(Url)
                               select a).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work.

```
        string url="/EmailAccounts/Index";// or One of the above value from file.
        var checkPermission = xml.Elements("AccessUrl").Elements("Url").Any(x => x.Value == url);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will behave slightly differently than intended since you use `==` instead of .`Contains(url)`.